# how to create customisable app icons Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, appicon

I'm currently developing my first IOS app and I want to give the user the option to pick an icon for the app. I'm currently giving the user the option to set the icon from a list of preset icons that I have created manually, but when I'm doing it like this I have to make every possible image, but i would like to give the user the option to pick a background colour and then pick a tint colour for the logo.

Is this possible?

This is how i would like to do it:

#### Background:

Select background:

[image]
[[image]][1]
[image]

#### Logo:

[image]

set tint: [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: check this.. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Comment: from what i can understand i will need to create each image from what it says here. is it possible to the logo and background as separate images and then placing them on top of each other? @BenRockey

Comment: you need to create 3 appicon set for 3 app icons.